# Update a subset of weights in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Does anyone know how to update a subset (i.e. only some indices) of the weights that are used in the forward propagation?

My guess is that I might be able to do that after applying compute_gradients as follows:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
grads_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, var_list=[weights, bias_h, bias_v])
```

...and then do something with the list of tuples in `grads_vars`.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a combination of `gather` and `scatter_update`. Here's an example that doubles the values at position `0` and `2`

```
indices = tf.constant([0,2])
data = tf.Variable([1,2,3])
data_subset = tf.gather(data, indices)
updated_data_subset = 2*data_subset
sparse_update = tf.scatter_update(data, indices, updated_data_subset)
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([init_op])
print "Values before:", sess.run([data])
sess.run([sparse_update])
print "Values after:", sess.run([data])
```

You should see

```
Values before: [array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)]
Values after: [array([2, 2, 6], dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I can use that with a 1D tensor. What about a 2D matrix (weights in my case)?

Comment: Reshape to 1d vector, compute linear indices, reshape back into matrix

Comment: if I do 
`data = tf.Variable([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
data = tf.reshape(data, [-1])`

I get `TypeError: Input 'ref' of 'ScatterUpdate' Op requires l-value input`

Comment: Hm...good point. One work-around is to keep your variables as 1D vectors, and apply reshape when you need it as a matrix

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to pull the `tf.Variable` into python (as a numpy array) using `npvar = sess.run(tfvar)`, then perform some operation on it such as `npvar[1, 2] = -10`.  Then you can upload the modified data back into tensorflow using `sess.run(tfvar.assign(npvar))`.

Obviously this is very slow and not really useful for training but it does work.

Comment: Really great! Maybe this way slows down a bit, but if used not inside the training loop, but simply at the very beginning, shaping custom values on subparts of weights matrix it is a very effective and simple way to make initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

```
# in TF2.0 you can solve with "tensor_scatter_nd_update"
# for example:
tensor = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # tf.rank(tensor) == 1
indices = [[1], [3], [4], [7]]  # num_updates == 4, index_depth == 1
updates = [9, 10, 11, 12]  # num_updates == 4
print(tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tensor, indices, updates))
# tf.Tensor([ 0 9  0 10  11  0  0 12], shape=(8,), dtype=int32)
```