# Tensorflow is too slow in a python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, machine-learning, tensorflow

I would like to create in **Tensorflow**, a function that for every line of a given data X, is applying the **softmax** function only for some sampled classes, lets say 2, out of K total classes, and returns a matrix S, where `S.shape = (N,K)` (N: the lines of the given Data and K the total classes).

The matrix S finally would contain zeros, and non_zero values in the indexes defined for every line by the sampled classes.

In simple python I use *advanced indexing*, but in Tensorflow I cannot figure out how to make it. My initial question was [this, where I present the numpy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568572/update-values-of-a-matrix-variable-in-tensorflow-advanced-indexing).

So I tried to find a solution in **Tensorflow** and the main idea was not to use the S as a 2-d matrix but as an 1-d array. The code looks like that:

```
num_samps = 2
S = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(N*K)))
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((K,D)))
tfx = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,D))
sampled_ind = tf.random_uniform(dtype=tf.int32, minval=0, maxval=K-1, shape=[num_samps])
ar_to_sof = tf.matmul(tfx,tf.gather(W,sampled_ind),transpose_b=True)
updates = tf.reshape(tf.nn.softmax(ar_to_sof),shape=(num_samps,))
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for line in range(N):
    inds_new = sampled_ind + line*K
    sess.run(tf.scatter_update(S,inds_new,updates), feed_dict={tfx: X[line:line+1]})

S = tf.reshape(S,shape=(N,K))
```

This is working, and the result is the expected. But it is running **extremely slow**. Why is that happening? How could I make that work faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While programming in tensorflow, it is crucial to learn a distinction between defining operations and executing them. Most of the functions starting with `tf.`, when you run in python *add operations to the computation graph*.

For example, when you do:

```
tf.scatter_update(S,inds_new,updates)
```

as well as:

```
inds_new = sampled_ind + line*K
```

multiple times, your computation graph grows beyond what is necessary, filling all the memory and slowing things down enormously.

What you should do instead is to *define* the computation one time, before the loop:

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
inds_new = sampled_ind + line*K
update_op = tf.scatter_update(S, inds_new, updates)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for line in range(N):
    sess.run(update_op, feed_dict={tfx: X[line:line+1]})
```

This way your computation graph contains only one copy of the `inds_new` and `update_op`. Note that when you execute `update_op`, the `inds_new` will be implicitly executed too, as it is its parent in the computation graph.

You should also know that `update_op` will probably have different results each time it is run and it is fine and expected.

By the way, a good way to debug this kind of problem is to visualize the computation graph using tensorboard. In code you add:

```
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('some_logdir', sess.graph_def)
```

and then run in console:

```
tensorboard --logdir=some_logdir
```

on the served html page there will be a picture of computation graph, where you can examine your tensors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working and answers exactly my question! But the problem still remains, the numpy code to create the matrix S is still faster than this. And i use only tensorlow functions... Do you know why that happens? Should i create a new op with c++ to get the speed up?

Comment: By faster you mean 20% faster, or 20x faster? 20% slower tensorflow on a CPU is an expected behavior. Do you have a good, CUDA-enabled GPU (and tensorflow installation that uses it)? Tensorflow is meant for situation where you use a GPU/a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that tf.scatter_update will return the Tensor S, which means a large memory copy in session run, or even network copy in distributed environment. The solution is, based on @sygi's answer:

```
update_op = tf.scatter_update(S, inds_new, updates)
update_op_op = update_op.op
```

Then in session run, you do this

```
sess.run(update_op_op)
```

This will avoid copy the large Tensor S.